# SELECT TOP(10) with nested GROUP BY

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have a query which works fine and delivers the result

```
SELECT PartyName, Risk, SUM(CAST(Amount AS DECIMAL)) SubTotal
FROM CustomerData
GROUP BY PartyName, Risk
```

Resulting data:

```
PartyName   Risk    SubTotal    

A           High    100
B           Med     25
A           Low     30
A           Med     70
B           Low     10
```

Now I want to `SUM` the total for each party and view the top 10. I am running into 2 problems in doing so:

**1. TOP(10) on SUM**

If I do the following:

```
SELECT TOP(10) PartyName, SUM(SubTotal) Total
FROM 
    (SELECT PartyName, Risk, SUM(CAST(Amount AS DECIMAL)) SubTotal
    FROM CustomerData
    GROUP BY PartyName, Risk) AS S
GROUP BY PartyName
```

I end up with the first 10 and not the 10 highest sums

**2. ERROR:**

> Column 'S.Risk' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

When I try the following:

```
SELECT TOP(10) PartyName, Risk, SUM(SubTotal) Total
FROM 
    (SELECT PartyName, Risk, SUM(CAST(Amount AS DECIMAL)) SubTotal
    FROM CustomerData
    GROUP BY PartyName, Risk) AS S
GROUP BY PartyName
```

What I need is

```
PartyName   Risk    SubTotal    Total   

A           High    100         200
B           Med     25          35
A           Low     30          200
A           Med     70          200
B           Low     10          30
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Issue 1:

If you want the "highest 10 subtotals" then you need an `ORDER BY`.

```
SELECT TOP(10) PartyName, SUM(SubTotal) Total
FROM 
    (SELECT PartyName, Risk, SUM(CAST(Amount AS DECIMAL)) SubTotal
    FROM CustomerData
    GROUP BY PartyName, Risk) AS S
GROUP BY PartyName
ORDER BY Total DESC
```

---

### Issue 2:

This gets a bit tricky, because you want to `GROUP BY` both `PartyName` and `Risk` while summing the `SubTotal`, however you also want to sum the `SubTotal` per `PartyName` without rolling them up.

One way to do this would be to join the table to another table that's nearly identical, however the second one will select the `Total` *per Party* (disregarding `Risk` entirely), so that we can get the grouped totals.

We can then merge that with our initial query `ON PartyName` to have a query that returns both the rolled-up data, as well as repeating `Total` per `Party`.

```
SELECT TOP(10) s.PartyName, s.Risk, s.SubTotal, s2.Total
FROM 
    (SELECT PartyName, Risk, SUM(CAST(Amount AS DECIMAL)) SubTotal
    FROM CustomerData
    GROUP BY PartyName, Risk) S
LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT PartyName, SUM(CAST(Amount AS DECIMAL)) Total
    FROM CustomerData
    GROUP BY PartyName) S2 
ON S.PartyName = S2.Partyname
```

Comment: I want to go ahead and create a view. Any other way to do it without `order by`?

Comment: I don't believe a view would be the best way to accomplish this, being that you'd need to take out your `TOP 10` and `ORDER BY`, and do `SELECT TOP 10 * FROM myView ORDER BY Total DESC`. Perhaps you'd be better off with a [table function](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191165(v=sql.105).aspx) so that your query can simply be: `SELECT * FROM Top10()`. If you insist on using a view, then make the table function, and put the query above into your view.

Comment: @SanjnaMalpani Also, I didn't realize what you wanted in regards to the second issue. I've modified my code to select SubTotal *and* Total.

Comment: Including `Risk` in Group By does not sum the total anymore

Comment: Thanks for the edit. `Total` and `SubTotal` are the same. It is not being summed up

Comment: Oh, I think I've finally understood. You want the total *per Party* to be in the right-most column `Total`. Give me a sec and I'll edit.

Comment: Total and SubTotal are still the same

Comment: @SanjnaMalpani I have created a copy of your table locally, populated it with data, and ran the query included in this edit. `Total` and `SubTotal` are *not* the same, unless the information you've supplied to us is not correct. If you look at the sub-queries themselves, it's very clear that the second is grouping total by ONLY `Party`, whereas the first is grouping by `Party` AND `Risk`. If you'd like to include a minimal version of your initial `CustomerData` table on a site like [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/), I can investigate further.

Answer (score 0):

If Risk is needed in the outer query, GROUP BY it at the bottom.

```
SELECT TOP(10) PartyName, Risk, SUM(SubTotal) Total
FROM 
    (SELECT PartyName, Risk, SUM(CAST(Amount AS DECIMAL)) SubTotal
    FROM CustomerData
    GROUP BY PartyName, Risk) AS S
GROUP BY PartyName, Risk
```

OR

```
SELECT TOP 10 * FROM 
(   SELECT PartyName, Risk, SUM(SubTotal) Total
   FROM 
       (SELECT PartyName, Risk, SUM(CAST(Amount AS DECIMAL))           SubTotal
       FROM CustomerData
       GROUP BY PartyName, Risk) AS S
   GROUP BY PartyName, Risk
)
ORDER BY Total DESC
```

Comment: Added 3rd level nesting...could likely be made more efficient. :-)

Comment: Total doesnt sum up subTotal :(

Answer (score 0):

In the first statement that u used, that with the TOP (10), Add at the end: ORDER BY Total DESC. Thats all!:

```
SELECT TOP(10) PartyName, SUM(SubTotal) Total 
FROM (SELECT PartyName, Risk, SUM(CAST(Amount AS DECIMAL)) SubTotal 
      FROM CustomerData GROUP BY PartyName, Risk) AS S 
GROUP BY PartyName
ORDER BY Total DESC
```