# SELECT TOP N with distinct/unique field values

Tags: sql, t-sql

Based on the answer to a previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44569652/6198223) of mine. I end up with a result set something like:

```
PartyName   Risk    SubTotal    Total   

A           High    100         280
B           Med     25          45
A           Low     30          280
A           Med     70          280
B           Low     10          45
C           High    110         170
C           Med     60          170
D           Low     30          30
A           Med     80          280
B           Low     10          45
```

What I need is to SELECT TOP N unique PartyName with highest Amounts, i.e if N = 2 the result should be:

```
PartyName   Risk    SubTotal    Total   

A           High    100         280
A           Low     30          280
A           Med     70          280
C           High    110         170
C           Med     60          170
A           Med     80          280
```

all entries with the highest N `Total` values.

Tried this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT TOP(10) s.PartyName, s.Risk, s.SubTotal, s2.Total
FROM 
    (SELECT PartyName, Risk, SUM(CAST(Amount AS DECIMAL)) SubTotal
    FROM CustomerData
    GROUP BY PartyName, Risk) S
LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT PartyName, SUM(CAST(Amount AS DECIMAL)) Total
    FROM CustomerData
    GROUP BY PartyName) S2 
ON S.PartyName = S2.Partyname
```

But doesn't work

Comment: Can you clarify the expected result? Are you looking for all the entries for the n=2 parties which have the highest totals?

Comment: So you want a set of data that has the top 2 totals values and then you want all records from the entire set that are >= those top two totals?

Comment: Yes, I want TOP (N) unique PartyName, with the Total being the criteria for determining TOP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Off the top off my head, maybe something like this:

```
if object_id('tempdb.dbo.#test') is not null drop table #test
create table #test
(
    partyname varchar(50),
    Risk varchar(50), 
    amount int
)

insert into #test
select 'A','High',50
union all select 'B','Med',  15
union all select 'A','Low',   12
union all select 'A','Med' ,  43
union all select 'B','Low' ,   65
union all select 'C','High',    12
union all select 'C','Med' ,   789
union all select 'D','Low' ,   12
union all select 'A' ,'Med',    34
union all select 'B' ,'Low',    43

SELECT
    main.PartyName, 
    main.Risk, 
    main.SubTotal, 
    TotalValues.Total 
FROM
    --get party+risk+subtotal
    (
            SELECT PartyName, Risk, SUM(CAST(Amount AS DECIMAL)) SubTotal
            FROM #test
            GROUP BY PartyName, Risk 
     ) main
--get total by partyname with a rownum to get top N, where N=2
INNER JOIN 
    (SELECT
        b.partyName, b.Total, row_number() over (order by Total desc) as rid
    FROM 
            (
                SELECT b.PartyName, SUM(CAST(Amount AS DECIMAL)) as Total  
                FROM #test b
                group by b.PartyName
            )  as b
    ) as TotalValues
    on TotalValues.partyName = main.partyName
    and TotalValues.rid <= 2 --n = 2
order by 
    main.partyname,
    TotalValues.Total
```

Comment: End up with every row being RowNumber 1

Comment: hmm... try changing the order by from main.rownumber to main.partyname, main.rownumber... not seeing why they would all be 1 at the moment.

Comment: if all the RowNumbers are assigned 1, how would order by clause change anything?

Comment: Well, not seeing a reason right away and not having an easy way to create the data that it would return all 1s so was thinking you were just seeing the 1 at the top because that is what the sort would have done.  There would have been 2,3,4.... you just may not have seen it.  Hard to work w\ w\o data.

Comment: I have 906 entries in my table and all have the RowNumber as 1

Comment: This works for me... I took your data and did my best to recreate to take the guesswork out of it.  See edits above.

Comment: I just ran your solution and still doesn't work. The result is:
A High 50 139 1
A Low 12 139 2
B Low 108 123 1
B Med 15 123 2
C High 12 801 1
C Med 789 801 2
D Low 12 12 1

Comment: Must have misunderstood what you wanted then b/c I thought that was it...

Comment: If N=2, I would like all entries of A and C, since A and C have the highest totals, greater than C and D

Comment: Oh.  Ok. Last shot then I gotta go.  See changes above.

Comment: It works, thank you! If you could answer a follow up question that would be great. I wrapped the query into a view. When I execute the view I do not get the items ordered. I have to put an additional `ORDER BY` on my view. Any idea why?

Comment: You cannot have an order by in a view, so the order is determined by sql server.

Answer (score 0):

I think this version should do what you want:

```
SELECT TOP (10) WITH TIES PartyName, Risk,
       SUM(CAST(Amount AS DECIMAL)) as SubTotal,
       MAX(SUM(CAST(Amount AS DECIMAL))) OVER (PARTITION BY PartyName) as Total
FROM CustomerData
GROUP BY PartyName, Risk
ORDER BY Total DESC, PartyName;
```

EDIT:

The above gives all rows tied with the 10th.  If you want all rows with the 10 distinct values, then let's use `DENSE_RANK()`:

```
SELECT cd.*
FROM (SELECT cd.*, DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY Total DESC) as seqnum
      FROM (SELECT TOP (10) WITH TIES PartyName, Risk,
                   SUM(CAST(Amount AS DECIMAL)) as SubTotal,
                   MAX(SUM(CAST(Amount AS DECIMAL))) OVER (PARTITION BY PartyName) as Total
            FROM CustomerData
            GROUP BY PartyName, Risk
           ) cd
     ) cd
WHERE seqnum <= 10
ORDER BY Total DESC, PartyName;
```

Comment: Doesn't, it just gives me top 10 rows

Comment: @SanjnaMalpani . . . No, it gives additional rows when they are tied with the tenth.  That may not be what you want, though.

Answer (score 0):

1st we get a set of data with the totals, next we find the range of totals of interest, finally we get teh results...

Untested:

```
WITH mAgg AS (SELECT partyName
                  , Risk
                  , sum(cast(amount as decimal(10,2)) over (partition by partyName, Risk) as subTotal
                  , sum(cast(amount as decimal(10,2)) over (partition by partyName) as Total
             FROM CustomerData),

  mRange as (SELECT distinct top 2 total from mAgg order by total desc)


SELECT * FROM mAgg where Total >=  (SELECT min(total) 
                                   FROM mRange))
```

Or maybe we could just dense_rank() over (partition by total desc) and then get the anything with rank >=2 or N...

Comment: I am getting syntax error `Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 3
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'over'.`. Probably something basic I am missing out. But, I have no clue how `over` and `partition` work